# Way to run a firefox macro at a set time of day?

Tags: windows-7, cron, firefox-extensions, imacros

I am using Firefox v3.6.13 and [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) v7.0.3.0 on Windows 7.

I have a macro that I wish to execute once every 24 hours and one minute on a website that only lets me do my task once 24 hours and a minute have elapsed since the last time.

Can I do this with iMacros or in combination with some other plug-in or cron job type of functionality?

Comment: Have you tried the Task Scheduler built into windows 7 to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following image it seems that there is an URL to run the macro.

[image]

So, you can [schedule a task with the Task Scheduler](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/132903-task-scheduler-create-task.html), for example:

```
firefox.exe http://run.imacros.net/?m=logins%5Ciopusforum.iim
```